# Add Skype meeting to the calendar event

Tags: angularjs, office365, skype-for-business, ucwa, outlook-api

Currently, am integrating the Outlook calendar with the web application by Outlook Calendar REST API and Angular JS.

I'm trying to add a Skype for Business meeting functionality to y app. I have created the Skype meeting link using the UCWA API with help of the below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/ucwa/ScheduleAnOnlineMeeting

Create Meeting Request

[image: Create Meeting Request]

Create Meeting Response

[image: Create Meeting Response]

When I try to add the OnlineMeetingURL to the Calendar, it's not updating. I receive null for OnlineMeetingURL in the response. It's not showing any error but not showing any error but not updating. I have tried with setting OnlineMeeting object also. No luck.

Calendar Save Request

[image: Calendar Save Request]

Calendar Save Response

[image: Calendar Save Response]

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I have the same problem. The work around is just to send the URL in the event body!

Comment: OnlineMeetingUrl is a read only property

Comment: Then how to add the meeting URL to the calendar?